# how to disable var_dump() in xdebug?

Tags: php, xdebug

Is it possible to switch off `var_dump()` in PHP application when using with Xdebug? I have used several `var_dump()` which break the page. I want some function or way so that it is possible to switch off/on the `var_dump()` output and so it is possible to see the whole page structure without the dumped data for debug purpose.

Comment: how hard is it to comment them out by hand or with an IDE find and replace?

Comment: If you don't want the debugging messages to be displayed, how about logging to a file instead? You are going to delete or comment those var_dumps out anyway, aren't you?

Comment: those var_dump() not in one page. It is quite hard to go along all the pages and comment it out. Yes i will comment out all when i finish the project but it is not that time. I need to show some people the progress and those var_dump() makes the page messy. after showing it i want to switch it on to show the dumps.

Comment: You cannot. Write your own var_dump-like function. Find in your IDE var_dump and replace it to your new function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're not wanting var_dump to output anything at all (regardless of xdebug)

```
// here var_dump is enabled
$varDumpEnabled = !true;
assert($varDumpEnabled, var_dump('whatever'));
```

nutshell.. when the first argument for `assert1` is `false`, var_dump is evaluated..   when the first argument for `assert` is true, var_dump isn't evaluated.

Answer (score 39):

Put this in the `php.ini` settings

```
xdebug.overload_var_dump=0
```

Otherwise, you can set this also at runtime with:

```
ini_set("xdebug.overload_var_dump", "off");
```

Comment: Actually this turns of only the xdebug formatting, var_dump itself is not disabled.

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Using xampp v3.2.2 and Xdebug v2.2.5

Comment: @xzdead, don't forget to restart apache or fpm

Comment: [xdebug.overload_var_dump has been removed](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#removed-xdebug.overload_var_dump)

Answer (score 1):

Starting on Xdebug/3, the [`xdebug.overload_var_dump` directive is gone](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#removed-xdebug.overload_var_dump). Instead, the feature is controlled through the general purpose [`xdebug.mode` directive](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode). Adding `develop` to the comma-separated mode list enables [development helpers](https://xdebug.org/docs/develop), removing it disables them.

Comment: _This setting can only be set in php.ini or files like 99-xdebug.ini that are read when a PHP process starts (directly, or through php-fpm). You can not set this value in .htaccess and .user.ini files, which are read per-request, nor through php_admin_value as used in Apache VHOSTs and PHP-FPM pools._